# AngularJS Dropdown Selected value set in edit

Tags: angularjs

I have one query regarding dropdown selected value.
Project dropdown

```
$rootScope.projects = response;
```

First I am getting project list by using angularjs.
This is my Project dropdown.

Whenever doing edit how can I set proper value to project dropdown.

```
<div class="form-group width50">
  <label class="width30 marginTop fl">Project Name</label>
  <div id="selectProject_dd" class="selectbox travel_drop-downs width50 push-right-10 push-top-15">
    <div class="select">
      <span class="tr_txt">Please Select Project</span>
    </div>
    <span class="admin-sprite f_dropdown_icon"></span> 
    <select id='project-dropdown' ng-model="projectDropDown"
      ng-selected="projectDropDown"
      ng-options="project as project.projectName for project in projects"
      ng-change="onchangeProject(projectDropDown)">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please post what your problem is and what you have tried so far

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set default value of select box in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380951/how-do-i-set-default-value-of-select-box-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
<select ng-init="projectDropDown = projects[0]" id='project-dropdown' ng-model="projectDropDown" ng-options="project as project.projectName for project in projects"
  ng-change="onchangeProject(projectDropDown)"></select>
```

By using [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) directive, and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894934/setting-angular-select-ng-init-to-first-value-in-array) make ng-init more clear for you.

Comment: As far as I know is best practice to define the initial value in the JS code instead of the HTML.